# Set same width for many tables while the lengths of contents in each table are not equal?

Tags: html, css, xslt

I have an .xsl file to create 4 tables. Problem is: the contents of all the tables will be inserted automatically through an .xml file, so they are not fixed. In the example below, I insert certain contents and you see the widths of all the tables are not equal, the tables also do not stay in the middle of the page.

How should I update my CSS part below, so that with any inserted contents, all 4 tables have the same width and stay in the middle of the page?

```css
.frame {
    font-family: Verdana;
}
    
.div1 {
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-left:80px;
}
    
.div2 {
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-left:80px;
}
    
.div3 {
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-left:80px;
}
    
.div4 {
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-left:80px;
}
    
.table1 {
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-weight: bold;
} 
.table1 td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 380px;  
}
.table1 tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border: none;
}
    
.table2 {
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}   
.table2 th {
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgb(0,116,188);
    color: white;
}
.table2 td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.table2 tr:nth-child(1) td {
    border: none;
}
.table2 tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border: none;
}
.table2 tr:nth-last-child() td {
    border: none;
}
.table2 tr:nth-last-child(1) td {
    border: none;
}
    
.table3 {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table3 th {
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgb(0,116,188);
    color: white;
}
.table3 td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.table3 tr:nth-child(1) td {
    border: none;
}
.table3 tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border: none;
}
.table3 tr:nth-child(3) td {
    border: none;
}
.table3 tr:nth-child(4) td {
    border: none;
}
.table3 tr:nth-child(5) td {
    border: none;
}
.table3 tr:nth-last-child() td {
    border: none;
}
.table3 tr:nth-last-child(1) td {
    border: none;
}
    
.table4 {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}   
.table4 th {
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgb(0,116,188);
    color: white;
}
.table4 td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.table4 tr:nth-child(1) td {
    border: none;
}
.table4 tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="div1">
    <table class="table1" style="margin-top:20px">
      <tr>
         <td>Contract</td>
         <td>ABC XYZ</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> <br/> </td>
         <td> <br/> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Informations about Patients of</td>
         <td>Dr. William Hills (ID: 123456789)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Quartal/Year of treated Patient</td>
         <td>Q4-2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Treatment carried out by</td>
         <td>Dr. William Hills (ID: 123456789)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Start date Import</td>
         <td>201610011335</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Quantity of enrolled Patients</td>
         <td>126</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="div2">
    <table class="table2" style="font-size:12pt">
      <tr>
         <td colspan="7" style="font-weight: bold; color:rgb(0,116,188)">Changes of following patients</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td colspan="7"/>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Birthday</th>
              <th>Insurance No.</th>
              <th>Contractstatus</th>
              <th>Begin date</th>
              <th>End date</th>
              <th>Reason</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Frank Harrison</td>
              <td>01.12.1959</td>
              <td>G987654321</td>
              <td>
                 <b>Activated</b>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <b>01.04.2017</b>
              </td>
              <td/>
              <td/>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Peter Smith</td>
              <td>04.12.1969</td>
              <td>G543267sfgsfgsgdgdfgssgs7895642gfdfsfsfsd89</td>
              <td>
                 <b>Terminated</b>
              </td>
              <td>01.01.2016</td>
              <td>
                 <b>31.03.2017</b>
              </td>
              <td>Cancelled</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td colspan="7"> Some notations here</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="div3">
    <table class="table3" style="font-size:12pt">
        <tr>
           <td colspan="6" style="margin-left:80px; font-weight:bold; color:rgb(0,116,188)">Title of second table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="6"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="6">101 Dalmatians is a 1996 American live-action family comedy film based on Walt Disney's animated 1961 movie adaptation of Dodie Smith's 1956 novel The Hundred and One Dalmatians. Directed by Stephen Herek and co-produced by John Hughes and Ricardo Mestres, it stars Glenn Close, Hugh Laurie, Mark Williams, Tim McInnerny, Jeff Daniels and Joely Richardson. In contrast with the 1961 film, none of the animals talk in this version. Released on November 27, 1996 by Walt Disney Pictures, the film was praised for its faithfulness to the animated classic. It received mixed reviews, but was a commercial success, grossing $320.6 million in theaters against a $75 million budget. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="6"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="6"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Birthday</th>
           <th>Insurance No.</th>
           <th>Office</th>
           <th>Date for Q4-2016</th>
           <th>Reason</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Adolph_Blaine_Charles_David_Earl_Frederick_Gerald_Hubert_Irvin_ John Kenneth Lloyd Martin Nero Oliver Paul</td>
           <td>04.12.1969</td>
           <td>G543996789</td>
           <td>Activated<br/>
              <b>01.07.2016</b>
           </td>
           <td>Activated<br/>
              <b>01.04.2016</b>
              <br/>
           </td>
           <td/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Peter Tester</td>
           <td>01.12.1959</td>
           <td>G987677321</td>
           <td>
              <b>Activated</b>
              <br/>01.01.2016</td>
           <td>
              <b>Terminated</b>
              <br/>
              <b>01.01.2016</b>
              <br/>
              <b>30.06.2016</b>
           </td>
           <td>Late feedback about changing the residence</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="6"> Some notations here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="div4">
    <table class="table4" style="font-size:12pt">
        <tr>
           <td colspan="4" style="font-weight: bold; color:rgb(0,116,188)">Title of third table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="4"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Birthday</th>
           <th>Insurance No.</th>
           <th>Notice</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Fritz Ford</td>
           <td>30.01.1965</td>
           <td>D555555555</td>
           <td>PTD</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to add `table-layout:fixed;width:100%` on all your tables. This way, the width will always be 100% and the table cell contents would wrap. Keep in mind that adding `table-layout:fixed` will make all table-cells have equal width.

Of course if your tables are too long you would need javascript to achieve what you are after.

Comment: thank you. But I dont like this solution very much because in case the content of each table is short, the table width is still large. So it does not look beautiful. I need something more adaptive. :)

Comment: Does this mean that you would like all tables be the width of the largest table? This requires a lot of javascript, that would be an overkill for too many tables.

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. Ok, if it is too difficult, I will play with your solution. Btw, when I use your method, the table cell contents are not wrapped as you said, but overlap to the next cell. How should I correct it?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet replicating this behavior? What you describe usually happens if white-space:nowrap is applied. Try applying white-space:normal on the tables.

Comment: You can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/vs4sytca/  I tried `white-space:normal` but it does not work.

Comment: Here the opposite problem is seen from what you described, the tables are not short, quite the opposite. I think now is the time to ask, what you consider to be 'beautiful'. What I would do in this case would be to use a table width:100% and wrap all tables inside a scrollable container like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vs4sytca/2/ Obviously, take any description title and text outside the scrollable div as I show with the second table. You can also style a bit better by adding a border to the overflown divs, etc

Comment: thanks a lot @scooterlord. Could you post your link again. Your link above does not work :(

Comment: Thank you! I think my problem is complicated because all the tables will be printed. So a horizontal scroll bar is not a good choice here because some contents will be hidden when we print. When you said "the table cell contents would wrap", I think the text inside each cell would be wrapped when it is too long. That I think "beautiful".

Comment: Tables are very limited concerning their table cells content - the table cell width is set arbitrarily depending on the content. Your best bet would be simple tables (without table-layout:fixed) as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/vs4sytca/4/ The content would wrap, but too much content and it would wrap awkwardly, especially at small resolutions. Try using media queries and adding overflow-x to parent divs for small resolution devices

Comment: ...last but not least, also try using word-break:break-all; on the tables; this would break all words without respecting any rules to try to maintain the table width given. https://jsfiddle.net/vs4sytca/5/

Comment: thanks a lot @scooterlord! Your final solution would be the best solution in this case. Thanks again. I used 2 account to upvote for your help. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help :/